# how to pass messages between two simulated openthread on windows 10 with C language

Tags: openthread

I am new to opwnthread, however, I figured it out how to simulate thread I am able to pass messages between them with cmd but I want to pass it now with C language program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow the [OpenThread on Windows readme](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples/drivers/windows).

Note, however, that OpenThread's Windows integration has not been actively maintained for some time. While Windows builds are still a part of OpenThread's continuous integration, the Windows continuous integration only test basic compilation. We welcome anyone who is willing to help actively maintain OpenThread's Windows support!